# Confused at + and ++ in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can't seem to figure out the difference between + and ++ relative coordinates in TikZ.

I understand ++. ++ specifies delta coordinates that are added to the last current point, the current point is then set to the new absolute current point (correct?):

```
\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) means:

set Current Point to (0,0)
add (1,0) to Current Point = (1,0)
set Current Point to (1,0)
add Current Point (1,0) to (0,1) = (1,1)
set Current Point to (1,1)
```

I can't seem to figure out that + does, when I try it out it looks like the coordinates in the +(x,y) are absolute coordinates rather than delta coordinates, but the manual says otherwise

Comment: Start from here and then manual makes sense :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/can-anyone-please-explain-vs-operator-in-pgf

Comment: I remember reading that section of the manual but I interpreted as all +(x,y) terms are relative to the first coordinate, hence a list of +() would generate a set of lines radiating from a single point, which it doesn't. I will look more closely at the question you refer to.

Comment: @rhody The pluses only affect the calculation of these relative coordinates, they do (`++`) or don’t update (`+`) the “current point for subsequent usages of relative coordinates.” The lines (or whatever is used) will always start from the last actual point. The set of lines radiating from a single point will always need a move-to operation. E.g. `\draw (12,34) -- +(1,0) +(0,0) -- +(0,1) + (0,0) -- + (left:1) + (0,0) -- + (270:1) + (0,0) circle (2pt);` vs. `\draw (12,34) -- ++(1,0) ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,1) ++ (0,-1) -- ++ (left:1) ++ (right:1) -- ++ (270:1) ++(90:1) circle (2pt);`

Comment: It is also important to recognize that `\draw (a,b) + (c,d) -- (e,f) + (g,h);` draws a line from `(a+c,b+d)` to `(e,f)` and then moves the current point to `(e+g,f+h)` (here the pluses do not matter as the following coordinate is an absolute one).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Your example:

`\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1)` means:

- the current point is `(0,0)`.
- draw a line from the current point `(0,0)` to `(0,0)+(1,0)` (vector addition) and move the current point to `(0,0)+(1,0)`.
- next draw a line from the current point `(0,0)+(1,0)` to `(0,0)+(1,0)+(0,1)` and move the current point to `(0,0)+(1,0)+(0,1)`.

Other examples are given as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (110:2) circle (1pt);
    \draw (110:2) -- +(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks for TikZ**:

- `\draw (110:2) -- +(0,-1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` (vector addition). The current point is still at `(110:2)`.
- `\draw (110:2) -- ++(0,-1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` (vector addition). The current point is moved to `(110:2)+(0,-1)`.
- `\draw (110:2) +(0,-1) -- +(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,1)`. The current point is still at `(110:2)`.
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) -- +(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)`. The current point is still at `(110:2)+(0,-1)`.
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) -- ++(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)`. The current point is moved to `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)` (which is equal to `(110:2)`).

### Edit:

`\draw (0,0) -- +(1,1) -- +(2,0)` means

- the current point is `(0,0)`.
- the first segment connecting `(0,0)` and `(0,0)+(1,1)`.
- the current point is still `(0,0)`.
- the second segment connecting the previous point `(0,0)+(1,1)` and `(0,0)+(2,0)`.

The key is `A -- B` connects `A` and `B` with a line no matter how `A` and `B` are defined.

Comment: +1; Thanks for this answer. It clears up quite a bit for me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In your notation what would the following do:

    `\draw (0,0) -- +(1,1) -- +(2,0);`

Does it say:

    `Current Point is (0,0);`
    `Draw line from (0,0) to (0,0)+(1,1);` 
    `Current point remains at (0,0);`
    `Draw line from (0,0) to (0,0)+(2,0);`

If I run this I get a triangle, not two lines radiating from (0,0)

Comment: I was looking again at the example shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/can-anyone-please-explain-vs-operator-in-pgf and what seems to be happening given:

    \draw (0,0) -- +(1,1) -- +(2,0)

    Current Point is `(0,0);'
    Draw line from `(0,0) to (0,0)+(1,1)` 
    Current Point is set to `(0,0)+(1,1)`
    Draw a line from current point `(0,0)+(1,1)
    to the point `(0,0)+(2,0)`

Seems like an odd thing to do?

Comment: @rhody: The current point is `(0,0)`, draw a line from `(0,0)` to `(0,0)+(1,1)` first and draw a line from the previous point `(0,0)+(1,1)` to `(0,0)+(2,0)`. `A -- B` connects `A` and `B` regardless of how `A` and `B` are defined.

Comment: Ok, I see what its doing now, I just need to let it sink in a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With +(2,0), it always adds to the original reference point (0,0) and does seem to be counter intuitive. Besides the next \draw probably will start a new anchor point anyway, so why keep it as the current point. I see ++(2,0) to be more clear to follow.