# Drawing a straight line over a coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose you want to draw a straight line over a coordinate named "cor" of which you don't know the position. Cor must be at the center of the line.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (cor) at (0,0) ;
  \draw (cor)+(180:2cm)--(cor)+(0:2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. It works if you use

```
\draw (cor)+(180:2cm)--+(2,0);
```

My question is: why it doesn't work in the first case? Shouldn't the two approaches bring the same result?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Related: [Confused at + and ++ in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113283)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because TikZ stops looking for the next coordinate when it finds a legitimate coordinate declaration. And since there is no other path on the stream nothing happens other than moving to the left of `(cor)`. In the first case you first move to `(cor)` then use a temporary relative coord, go back to `(cor)` and use the second relative coordinate.

If you want to perform a coordinate computation you can use

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (cor) at (0,0);
  \draw (cor)+(180:2cm)--($(cor)+(0:2cm)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

via `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble. Alternatively, you can say

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (cor) at (0,0);
  \draw (cor)+(180:2cm)--+(0:2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Because after the first relative `+` coordinate, TikZ goes back to `(cor)` (Stays there if you use `++`).

Comment: Alternatively, you can say `([shift={(0:2cm)}] cor)` (or `xshift=2cm` in this case) without `calc`. It might be helpful to note that a simple coordinate without `--`, `to`, `edge`, `..`, etc. is simply a move-to operation. So `(x1,y1) + (x2,y2)` will first move to `(x1,y1)` then to `(x1+x2,y1+y2)`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's the first paragraph. And in your second example the pen is moved back to `(x1,y1)`.

Comment: No. The “pen” is still at `(x1+x2,y1+y2)`, but further calculation of relative coordinates are done from `(x1,y1)`. See my comments to [Confused at + and ++ in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113283). What I meant with my previous comment also is that `(<c1>)+(<c2>)` is not seen as one entity (but works for move-tos and thus as a path-start) but simply to different operations.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don't get it. What's the difference ? The first sentence means `+(c2)` will be ignored in your example as part of the path and will be taken as a `move to`.