# Draw vertical line from node until it hits horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

please consider this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]   
        \node[fill=black] (a) {};
        \node[fill=black, xshift=\linewidth] (c) {};
        \node[xshift=\linewidth*0.7] (b) {...};

        \draw [name path=line1] (a) -- (b);
        \draw (b) -- (c);

        \node[draw, rectangle, above=of a, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=1cm] (foo1) {Foo 1};
        \node[draw, rectangle, right=0.5cm of foo1] (foo2) {Foo 2};

        \draw (foo1) -- TODO;
        \draw (foo2) -- TODO;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I fail to draw a straight vertical line from node foo1 and foo2 downwards to  path line1. I do not want to give absolute coordinates. I attempted to solve this problem with intersections, but as my starting position is a node, this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]   
        \node[fill=black] (a) {};
        \node[fill=black, xshift=\linewidth] (c) {};
        \node[xshift=\linewidth*0.7] (b) {...};

        \draw [name path=line1] (a) -- (b);
        \draw (b) -- (c);

      \node[draw, rectangle, above=of a, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=1cm] (foo1) {Foo 1};
        \node[draw, rectangle, right=0.5cm of foo1] (foo2) {Foo 2};

\path[name path=fl1] (foo1.270)coordinate(f1)--++(-90:2);
\path[name path=fl2] (foo2.270)coordinate(f2)--++(-90:2);
\path[name intersections={of=fl1 and line1,by={a}}];
\path[name intersections={of=fl2 and line1,by={b}}];
\draw (f1)--(a);
\draw (f2)--(b);

%        \draw (foo1) -- TODO;
   %     \draw (foo2) -- TODO;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. Could you maybe elaborate what --++ means?

Comment: Adding a + before a coordinate makes it relative to the current position. For example (0,1) -- +(1,2) will draw a line from (0,1) to (0+1,1+2). A ++ before a coordinate makes it relative and moves the current position to the coordinate. For example (0,1) -- ++(1,2) -- (0,1) draws lines between (0,1), (1,3), and (1,4).

Comment: You can find a comprehensive description here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113286/31034

Answer (score 4):

TikZ allows you to locate the point located at the intersection of the horizontal line passing through `a` and the vertical of `foo1` that you are looking for is the syntax `(foo1|-a)` or both with the syntax `(a-|foo1)`.

I quote the TikZ 3.1.4 manual

> In general, the meaning of `(p |- q)` is the *intersection of a
>   vertical line through `p` and a horizontal line through `q`*.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]   
        \node[fill=black] (a) {};
        \node[fill=black, xshift=\linewidth] (c) {};
        \node[xshift=\linewidth*0.7] (b) {...};

        \draw [name path=line1] (a) -- (b);
        \draw (b) -- (c);

        \node[draw, rectangle, above=of a, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=1cm] (foo1) {Foo 1};
        \node[draw, rectangle, right=0.5cm of foo1] (foo2) {Foo 2};

        \draw (foo1) -- (a-|foo1);
        \draw (foo2) -- (a-|foo2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is even more elegant!

Comment: This syntax is also used in another way to draw two perpendicular lines in a single path. For example `(a) -| (foo1)` draws a horizontal line from `(a)` which rotates at right angles right at the point `(a|-foo1)` and continues vertically to `(foo1)`.