# Connecting 2 coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz, when it comes to connecting 2 coordinates, what is the difference between the different amounts of +s and -s, such as -+ , --++ , -++ , --+.

Comment: Please, ilustrate your problem with small document with `tikz` picture and show what is your problem. To make yourself more familiar with `tikz` package, please read Ti*k*Z & PGF manula, first tutorial and *part III:  TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm*

Comment: Specifically, the differences between + and ++ is explained in section 2.15 _Specifying Coordinates_ on page 40 of the [PGF/TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (section/page numbers for version 3.1.9a as currently on CTAN).

Comment: Note that I think this is actually a good question, asking things that are in the manual is perfectly fine on the site, especially when the manual is for TikZ and 1321 pages long.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113283/86 help?

Answer (score 17):

Note that in TikZ, there is `--` (two dashes) operation, but there is no `-` (one dash) operation. The command `\draw (A)--(B);` means drawing a straight segment from `(A)` to `(B)`. The command `\draw (A)-(B);` returns an error. Operations `-|`, `|-`, `->`, ... have different meanings.

Many TikZ beginners seem confusing about `+` and `++`. To understand these, we need 2 things: connected path component, and the point for the next plus.

**Connected path components** A path is often composed by some connected path components. For example,

```
\draw 
(A)--(B)        % 1st connected path component
(C)--(D)--(E)   % 2nd connected path component
(F) node{$F$}   % 3rd connected path component
;
```

In a connected path component *without* `+` or `++`, **the point for the next plus** is exactly the starting point of that current connected path component.

```
\draw (A);            % the point for the next plus is A, but we do not care this.
\draw (A)--(B);       % the point for the next plus is A, but we do not care this.
\draw (A)--(B)--(C);  % the point for the next plus is A, but we do not care this.
```

When moving along a `connected path component` *with* `+` or `++`: Both `+` and `++` mean to plus with the point for next plus (that TikZ has already known just before). The only difference between them is: `+` keeps unchanged the point for next plus, while `++` updates the **new** point for the next plus:

```
\draw (A)--+(B); %  \draw (A)--($(A)+(B)$); the point for the next plus is A

\draw (A)--++(B); %  \draw (A)--($(A)+(B)$); the point for the next plus is A+B (useless in this case, since there is nothing to plus)
 
\draw (A)--++(B)--+(C); %  \draw (A)--($(A)+(B)$)--($(A)+(B)+(C)$); the point for the next plus is A+B (uselful in this case: to plus with C)
```

Now, please copy line by line of the following code, and compile to see different effects of `+` and `++`. That is all!

Hope this helps!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!30] (-2,-3) grid (6,5);
\fill (0,0) circle(2pt);
\path
(-1,-2) coordinate (A)  node[left]{$A$} 
(4,1) coordinate (B) node[right]{$B$}
(1,3.5) coordinate (C) node[above]{$C$}
($(A)+(B)$) node[right]{$A+B$}
($(A)+(C)$) node[above]{$A+C$}
($(B)+(C)$) node[above]{$B+C$}
($(A)+(B)+(C)$) node[above]{$A+B+C$}
;
\draw (A)--(B)--(C);

% tpftnp=the point for the next plus        

\draw (A)--(B)--+(C);           % same as (A)--(B)--($(A)+(C)$), tpftnp is A
\draw[blue] (A)--+(B)--(C);     % same as (A)--($(A)+(B)$)--(C), tpftnp is A
\draw[red] (A)--+(B)--+(C);     % same as (A)--($(A)+(B)$)--($(A)+(C)$), tpftnp is A
    
\draw[green] (A)--(B)--++(C);    % same as (A)--(B)--+(C), tpftnp is A, then C 
        
\draw[violet] (A)--+(B)--++(C);  % same as (A)--+(B)--+(C), tpftnp is A, then C
        
\draw[orange] (A)--++(B)--(C); % same as (A)--+(B)--(C), tpftnp is A, then B
\draw[cyan] (A)--++(B)--+(C);  % same as (A)--($(A)+(B)$)--($(A)+(B)+(C)$) tpftnp is A, then B
        
\draw[blue] (A)--++(B)--++(C); % same as (A)--++(B)--+(C), tpftnp is A, then B, then C
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Summary.** Going from the start to the end of each small piece of a path (called a connected path component), first take the starting point to be the point for the next plus, say (P); then

- if you meet a `+(A)` meaning `(P)+(A)`, keep unchanged `(P)` and go next;
- if you meet a `++(A)` meaning `(P)+(A)`, updating `(P)` as `(P)+(A)`, and go next;

till the end of the piece.

Comment: Where does the line from the origin to (A) get drawn?  It isn't part of the original \draw (A)--(B)--(C); is it?

Comment: @BillNace It was my mistake in posting image. I corrected with some changes.

Comment: @BlackMild If I correctly undestrand most of the `% the point for the next plus is A` are copy paste errors, where we would expect in some places `% the point for the next plus is B` (or `C`).