# Tikz: Moving the origin to a polar coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, relative, polar

Reading the documentation, I was under the impression that “++” changes the origin to that point. At the same time, I understand that a polar coordinate specifies a certain point by giving the angle and the distance from the previous origin.

So combining both ideas, I supposed that the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(30:1) -- (45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

would produce a second segment starting at the end of the first one, and moving by 1 with an angle of 45 from it, instead of the current result:

[image: Current Result]

from which we can see that the third point is simply located relative to the “original” origin.

My question is: there is a simple way of obtaining what I want? (that is to move the origin to a point given in polar coordinates?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `++` doesn't change the origin it just moves the reference for relative coordinates. But `(45:1)` is an absolute coordinate. I think you want `\draw (0,0) -- ++(30:1) -- +(45:1);`. If you need the origin, i.e. `(0,0)`, to be somewhere else, you can do `shift=(30:1)` in various instances. I'm not quite sure what you really want, though. As always with TikZ there are plenty ways of specifying coordinates in relation to other coordinates.

Comment: this may help --https://tikz.dev/tikz-design

Comment: If I have correctly understood the result you want to obtain, it is not necessary to change the origin of the coordinate system, it is enough to rotate it by 45° relative to the tangent of the current path.
which gives this `\draw (0,0) -- (30:1) -- ([turn]45:1);`

Comment: Many thanks @AndréC, your solution works!

Comment: Many thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel, your solution works!

Comment: for a detail explanation on + and ++, have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615851/140722