# TikZ: Polar coordinates referencing system

Tags: tikz-pgf

Many times I like to use polar coordinates but the reference frame is always at the origin.  This is a bother when I went to draw a specific angle and radius from a location other than the origin.  I end up having to do `xshift` and/or `yshift` or the `scope` environment.

Is it possible to have polar coordinates work from the location I start each time; that is, it interprets the starting point as its origin.  I don't just mean for one instance though.  If I say, `\draw (1,1) -- (30:1cm);` and then later use `\draw (-2,5) -- (60:1cm);` each location will be treated as the origin when the line is drawn.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {O};
\draw(-3,2) -- (45:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the picture, we see that the line was drawn right and down.  However, 45 degrees from (-3,2) should be up and right since my reference frame wasn't the origin here.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use relative coord quantifiers `++` and `+` ?

Comment: @percusse I do not.

Comment: Ok I'll try to dig up that question if someone else doesn't in the mean time. One of them is this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/can-anyone-please-explain-vs-operator-in-pgf and another  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113283/confused-at-and-in-tikz

Comment: If you want to draw a line to such an coordinates that is relative to another you can (have to) use the `shift` options: `\draw (3,1) -- ([shift={(30:1)}] 1,2);`.