# TikZ node distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have a question about proper spacing of paths and nodes.

I want the following picture:

[image: tikzimage]

And I am currently using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]  
\tikzset{
    block/.style= {draw, rectangle, align=center,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm},
    >={Classical TikZ Rightarrow[length=1.7mm]},
    XOR/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
        [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
        (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
        (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)}}
}
%}  
\node[] (k) {k};
\node[right=of k] (t) {t};
\node[block, below =2cm of t] (AES) {AES};
\node[above =1cm of AES] (splitof) {};
\node[XOR, below =1cm of AES] (xor) {};
\node[below =1.5cm of xor] (c) {c};

%% paths
\path[draw,->] (k) |- (AES);
\path[draw,->] (AES) edge (xor);
\path[draw,->] (t) edge (AES);
\path[draw,->,style={shorten <=-1.1mm}] (splitof) -- +(2, 0) |- (xor);
\path[draw,->] (xor) edge (c);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

What I do not understand is why I need this `style={shorten <=-1.1mm}` instruction on the hidden node. All the other arrows start perfectly aligned on their nodes but this one just starts a little spaces away otherwise.

Disclaimer: This is my first attempt at using Ti*k*Z and the above code is c&p work.

Comment: Nodes require some space around them, I guess. In your case, I would better go with `\coordinate[above =1cm of AES] (splitof) {};`

Comment: I have to confess that I was surprised to still see a little gap for `\node[above =1cm of AES, text width=0mm, inner sep=0mm] (splitof) {};` which have been my first guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a coordinate instead of your "hidden node" as even `\node[above =1cm of AES, text width=0mm, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm] (splitof) {};` seems to require some space.

Here is the code which works without shortening:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{%
        ,block/.style={%
            ,draw
            ,rectangle
            ,align=center
            ,minimum width=2cm
            ,minimum height=1cm
            }
        ,>={Classical TikZ Rightarrow[length=1.7mm]}
        ,XOR/.style={%
            ,draw
            ,circle,append after command={%
                [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
                (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
                (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
                }
            }
        }
    \node (k) {k};
    \node[right=of k] (t) {t};
    \node[block, below =2cm of t] (AES) {AES};%
    \coordinate[above =1cm of AES] (splitof) {};
    \node[XOR, below =1cm of AES] (xor) {};
    \node[below =1.5cm of xor] (c) {c};

    \path[draw,->] (k) |- (AES);
    \path[draw,->] (AES) edge (xor);
    \path[draw,->] (t) edge (AES);
    \path[draw,->] (splitof) -- +(2, 0) |- (xor);
    \path[draw,->] (xor) edge (c);  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively drop defining that altogether, and just use `\draw[->] (AES.north) ++(0,1cm) -- +(2, 0) |- (xor);`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. What's the difference between + and ++?

Comment: @Sarien See e.g. [Can anyone please explain + vs ++ operator in PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7643)/ With `++` the new point becomes the new reference point, so for example `\draw (1,1) -- +(1,0) -- +(0,1);` should draw a line from (1,1) to (2,1) to (1,2), because (1,1) is always the reference. With `\draw (1,1) -- ++(1,0) -- +(0,1);` you get a line from (1,1) to (2,1) to (2,2), because after `++(1,0)` the new reference point is (2,1).